# Posting image on yammer using Yammer Javascript SDK

Tags: yammer

I have been trying to post an attachment on Yammer using Yammer Javascript api. There is not much documentation available on Yammer regarding this. Can someone help me to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this may help you to solve the issue,

You can use `POST:/pending-attachments` yammer API for posting the images in yammer.

But If you want to create yammer post with images, `POST:/messages.json` can be used with attaching files - `attachment_N or pending_attachment_N` as a multipart form field.

Use this link for info - [Yammer message API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messages-json-post)

adding a sample code using JavaScript SDK -

```
let otherFormData = {
    "group_id": groupId,
    "body": message,
    "og_url": postUrl,
    "og_fetch": false,
    "og_title": title,
    "og_image": og_image,
    "og_description": summary,
    "og_object_type": og_object_type,
    "direct_to_user_ids": []
};
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("attachment1", imgData_Base64, AfileName);
for (let i in otherFormData) {
    formData.append(i, otherFormData[i]);
}

window.yam.platform.request({
    url: "messages.json",
    method: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (response) => {
        console.info("The request is successful. ", response); 
    },
    error: (err) => {
        console.info("There is an error in the request.", err);
    }
});
```